# How to stop and resume methods in parallel.invoke() in c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, invoke

I am working in Parellel.Invoke() function. And i am passing 4 return type of functions in that Parallel.Invoke().

Example:

```
               Parellel.Invoke(()=>returnvalue1=function1(p1,p2,p3),
              =>returnvalue2=function2(p1,p2),
              =>returnvalue3=function3(p1,p2),
              =>returnvalue4=function4(p1,p2));
```

Now in the above code, function1 returning some value and using that return value i want to pass in the function4 for parameter(p2).

How to do??

Comment: Let say. parameter p2 contains Deptno.

Comment: Functions can only run in parallel, if they are indenendent on each other. If parameter of function4 depends on result of function1, then these functions are NOT independent and therefore **cannot run in parallel**.

Comment: any other way to implement?

Comment: I want to improve web api performance if any other way..

Comment: You can identify, which functions are independent and run in parallel only these functions (maybe function1, function2 and function3 ?) . You can also try using some performance profiling tools to identify parts of your code that takes longest time to execute and try to optimize these parts.